# Redirect url using Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

How to redirect http://www.example.com/index.php/url-string to http://www.example.com/url-string using nginx

Comment: Am I missing something? `http://www.example.com/index.php/url-string` wouldn't be a valid url to begin with, as a php file can't be a directory..

Comment: so how to use location option in nginx config file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `url-string` can be anything, you would test for the existence of the original file before rewriting the URI with a named location. For example:

```
root /path/to/root;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /index.php$uri last;
}
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.